# How maker countdown timer to jquery or js with countdown time(H:i:s)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day.

*Sorry if question aleready exist - i dont find answer(if answer already exist plase give me link)*

I have code:

```
<div id="counttime">06:00:00</div> //h:i:s
```

I would like to make a countdown timer to the time at divas decreased over time by 1 second, and when the time will be 00:00 (i: s) will be performed function func ();

**The decision should not have be a third-party plug-ins, just pure js or jquery.**

i start make script but not know how make next...

```
var start = $('#counttime').html();
var CountArrTime = (start.split(':')).length;
alert(CountArrTime);
if(CountArrTime == '3'){
var h_start = CountArrTime[0]; // hours start
var m_start = CountArrTime[1]; // minutes start
var s_start = CountArrTime[2]; // secounds start
}
else if(CountArrTime == '2'){
var m_start = CountArrTime[0]; // minutes start
var s_start = CountArrTime[1]; // secounds start
}
```

in result(when time end) in div `counttime` should be 00:00 (minutes:secounds);

How to make a countdown the hours, minutes, seconds in my example?

Comment: Have a look at the questions on the right on this pages

Comment: Particularly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031680/javascript-jquery-countdown-timer-with-jsfiddle-example?rq=1

Comment: big thanks for help, i dont see this i past answer for my question) in 30 minutes.

Comment: @mplungjan thanks i made answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Thanks for help with links.***

**I make answer for my question:**

[<kbd>**JSFIDLE for test**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/7BZY4/)

```
var timer = $('#counttime').html();
timer = timer.split(':');

if(timer.length == 3){
var hours = timer[0];
var minutes = timer[1];
var seconds = timer[2];
}
else if(timer.length == 2){
var hours = 0;
var minutes = timer[0];
var seconds = timer[1];
}

if(hours > 0 || minutes > 0 || seconds > 0){

setInterval(function() {

seconds -= 1;


if (seconds < 0 && minutes > 0 && hours > 0) {
    minutes -= 1;
    seconds = 59;

}

else if (seconds < 0 && minutes == 0 && hours > 0) {
    hours -= 1;
    minutes = 59;
    seconds = 59;

}

else if (seconds < 0 && minutes > 0 && hours == 0) {
    hours = 0;
    minutes -= 1;
    seconds = 59;
}

if(hours > 0 && hours < 10 && ((hours+'').length != 2)) hours = '0' + hours;

if ((minutes < 10) && ((minutes+'').length < 2)) minutes = '0' + minutes;

if (seconds < 10 && length.seconds != 2) seconds = '0' + seconds;

   if(hours > 0){hoursN = hours + ':';}else{hoursN = '';}
    $('#counttime').html(hoursN + minutes + ':' + seconds);

}, 1000);

}
```

Comment: WAY too complex padding. `if(hours < 10) hours = '0' + hours;` will work just as well. Also `$('#counttime').html((hours?hours+":":"")+ minutes + ':' + seconds);`

Comment: @mplungjan nice, i dont know it, thanks. also i dont know that `hours?hours+":":""` can use in js...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on it.

Note the size and that it actually keeps time correctly if you go away and come back

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/rrjHF/)

```
function pad(num) {
  return num<10?"0"+num:num;
}
$(function() {
  var tCont = $('#counttime');
  var timer = tCont.html().split(':');

  if (timer.length === 2) timer.unshift(0);
  var endMilli= timer[0]*60*60*1000;
  endMilli += timer[1]*60*1000
  endMilli += timer[2]*1000;
  if(endMilli > 0) {
    var endTime = new Date(Date.now()+endMilli);   
    var tId = setInterval(function() {
      var diff = endTime.getTime()-Date.now();
      if (diff<=0) {
        tCont.html("00:00:00");
        clearInterval(tId);
      }
      else {
        var d = new Date(diff);
        hh = pad(d.getUTCHours()); 
        mm = pad(d.getMinutes());
        ss = pad(d.getSeconds());
        tCont.html(""+hh+":"+mm+":"+ss);
      }
    },300);      
  }
});
```