# 2 minutes time in HTML

Tags: html

Hello I need to have a 2 minutes timer on the screen after pressing a button (button is already generating a "random" word) and i will need the timer to reset every time i press the button

this is for a game i am making.

here is the code i have

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
     <title>Untitled</title>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
// Use the following variable to specify
// the number of random words
var NumberOfWords = 28

var words = new BuildArray(NumberOfWords)

// Use the following variables to
// define your random words:
words[1] = "bob"
words[2] = "bob1"
words[3] = "bob2"
words[4] = "bob3"
words[5] = "bob4"
words[6] = "bob5"
words[7] = "bob6"
words[8] = "bob7"
words[9] = "bob8"
words[10] = "bob9"
words[11] = "bob10"
words[12] = "bob11"
words[13] = "bob12"
words[14] = "bob13"
words[15] = "bob14"
words[16] = "bob15"
words[17] = "bob16"
words[18] = "bob17"
words[19] = "bob19"
words[20] = "bob18"
words[21] = "bob20"
words[22] = "bob21"
words[23] = "bob22"
words[24] = "bob23"
words[25] = "bob24"
words[26] = "bob25"
words[27] = "bob26"
words[28] = "bob27"

function BuildArray(size){
this.length = size
for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++){
this[i] = null}
return this
}

function PickRandomWord(frm) {
// Generate a random number between 1 and NumberOfWords
var rnd = Math.ceil(Math.random() * NumberOfWords)

// Display the word inside the text box
frm.WordBox.value = words[rnd]
}
//-->

</SCRIPT>

<body>
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">Made by George Walls................. Happy Christmas............Good luck guessing <3 <3</marquee>

  
 
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<FORM NAME="WordForm">

<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON onClick="PickRandomWord(document.WordForm)"
VALUE="Press for next word"><br> 
<INPUT TYPE=text SIZE=100 NAME="WordBox" ><BR>

</FORM>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript/jquery countdown timer with JSfiddle example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031680/javascript-jquery-countdown-timer-with-jsfiddle-example)

Comment: There is no timing in HTML, but you have tagged the question with “html” only. Moreover, your JavaScript code shows no attempt at setting up any timing. You should not expect others to write code for you, just help solving problems when writing code.

Comment: Hello i am asking for help not asking for someone to do it for me

Answer (score 1):

I set two variables: total is a constant that represent the total of time and timer is a variable that will be decreased every second inside the function setInterval.

I guess is this that you need.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
     <title>Untitled</title>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
// Use the following variable to specify
// the number of random words

var NumberOfWords = 28




var words = new BuildArray(NumberOfWords)

// Use the following variables to
// define your random words:
words[1] = "bob"
words[2] = "bob1"
words[3] = "bob2"
words[4] = "bob3"
words[5] = "bob4"
words[6] = "bob5"
words[7] = "bob6"
words[8] = "bob7"
words[9] = "bob8"
words[10] = "bob9"
words[11] = "bob10"
words[12] = "bob11"
words[13] = "bob12"
words[14] = "bob13"
words[15] = "bob14"
words[16] = "bob15"
words[17] = "bob16"
words[18] = "bob17"
words[19] = "bob19"
words[20] = "bob18"
words[21] = "bob20"
words[22] = "bob21"
words[23] = "bob22"
words[24] = "bob23"
words[25] = "bob24"
words[26] = "bob25"
words[27] = "bob26"
words[28] = "bob27"

function BuildArray(size){
this.length = size
for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++){
this[i] = null}
return this
}

function PickRandomWord(frm) {
// Generate a random number between 1 and NumberOfWords
var rnd = Math.ceil(Math.random() * NumberOfWords)

// Display the word inside the text box
frm.WordBox.value = words[rnd]
timer = total;
}
//-->
var timer = 30;
const total = 31; //1 plus to display 30 when reset timer
setInterval(function(){
    
    timer--;
    if(timer>0)  
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML =timer;
    
},1000)
</SCRIPT>

<body>
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">Made by George Walls................. Happy Christmas............Good luck guessing <3 <3</marquee>

  
 
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<FORM NAME="WordForm">

<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON onClick="PickRandomWord(document.WordForm)"
VALUE="Press for next word"><br> 
<INPUT TYPE=text SIZE=100 NAME="WordBox" ><BR>

</FORM>
Timer:<div id="timer">30</div>

</body>
</html>
```